# Chopin Nocturne in C sharp minor (posth.) note mistake

Tags: piano, chopin

In Chopin's C sharp minor Nocturne (no. 20, op. posth.) measure 15 the fourth and last notes of the left hand appear to be B in every music sheet that I can find online:

[image]

However, it seems that all the professional piano videos (for example [this one](https://youtu.be/DqpPRj6UZqc) at 1:03) of this piece play C sharp instead.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible these pianists are using out-of-date scores that include a mistake, or that some sloppy preparation has assumed a C♯ since so many other measures use it.

The official Chopin Institute uses a B in its publications. And here is Chopin's manuscript:

[image]

Oddly, the first apperance of this (second line, m. 4) is unclear whether this is a C♯ or a B; perhaps this is what has led to the confusion?

But when this figure returns (fifth line, m. 5), it's *very* clearly a B. For this reason, and because it's the version officially approved by the Chopin Institute, I would assume the use of B in both instances.

Comment: Thanks, how did you find that Chopin institute approved the B version? Can you provide a link?

Comment: @ziv I looked at a score in my institution's library, but if you're outside the US you can find it on [IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Nocturne_in_C-sharp_minor,_B.49_(Chopin,_Fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric)); it's the second score from the top, it looks like.

Comment: When you zoom in on measure 4 of second line, you will see that it is a B with a small mark next to it.

Comment: This doesn’t seem like Chopin’s manuscript. It’s more likely a copy made by someone else. His writing is different in comparison to the one in the picture. Here is an original manuscript in the pic;[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YgQX.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YgQX.jpg)

Comment: The handwriting doesn't look terribly different to me, especially considering that the image here is clearly a working copy while the one in the question appears to be a fair copy.

Comment: So what do you think it the right note?

Answer (score 0):

The Henle Urtext edition of the Nocturnes contains two versions of the C# minor, both based on autograph manuscripts, and both of which have B.

The Rousseau recording is incorrect, but here are some more established artists who do play B.

- [Yundi Li](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tVV3SIvncD4)
- [Jan Lisiecky](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cykgz9nIRtI)
- [Vladimir Ashkenazi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5qeuVOIbHk)
- [Lang Lang](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mbTn_2HlNTw)

Source material for the Nocturne can be found at [Online Chopin Variorum Edition](https://chopinonline.ac.uk/ocve/browse/). Note that the piece is not listed with the Nocturnes. Filter by "Works" and look for "Lento con gran espressione".